# how to use CRF in tensorflow keras?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, crf

The code is like this:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from keras_contrib.layers import CRF
from tensorflow import keras

def create_model(max_seq_len, adapter_size=64):
    """Creates a classification model."""

    # adapter_size = 64  # see - arXiv:1902.00751

    # create the bert layer
    with tf.io.gfile.GFile(bert_config_file, "r") as reader:
        bc = StockBertConfig.from_json_string(reader.read())
        bert_params = map_stock_config_to_params(bc)
        bert_params.adapter_size = adapter_size
        bert = BertModelLayer.from_params(bert_params, name="bert")

    input_ids = keras.layers.Input(shape=(max_seq_len,), dtype='int32', name="input_ids")
    # token_type_ids = keras.layers.Input(shape=(max_seq_len,), dtype='int32', name="token_type_ids")
    # output         = bert([input_ids, token_type_ids])
    bert_output = bert(input_ids)
    print("bert_output.shape: {}".format(bert_output.shape))  # (?, 100, 768)

    crf = CRF(len(tag2idx))
    logits = crf(bert_output)
    model = keras.Model(inputs=input_ids, outputs=logits)
    model.build(input_shape=(None, max_seq_len))

    # load the pre-trained model weights
    load_stock_weights(bert, bert_ckpt_file)

    # freeze weights if adapter-BERT is used
    if adapter_size is not None:
        freeze_bert_layers(bert)

    model.compile('adam', loss=crf.loss_function, metrics=[crf.accuracy])

    model.summary()

    return model
```

I am using tensorflow keras and also use keras_contrib package, to do NER. it seems the tensorflow keras package does not work well with keras_contrib package.

The Traceback information is listed below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:/_gitclone3/bert_examples/bert_ner_example_eval.py", line 120, in <module>
    model = create_model(max_seq_len, adapter_size=adapter_size)
  File "F:/_gitclone3/bert_examples/bert_ner_example_eval.py", line 101, in create_model
    logits = crf(bert_output)
  File "C:\Users\yuexiang\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\base_layer.py", line 443, in __call__
    previous_mask = _collect_previous_mask(inputs)
  File "C:\Users\yuexiang\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\base_layer.py", line 1311, in _collect_previous_mask
    mask = node.output_masks[tensor_index]
AttributeError: 'Node' object has no attribute 'output_masks'
```

How do I use CRF with tensorflow keras?

Answer (score 2):

I run into a similar problem and spent a lot of time trying to get things to work. Here's what worked for me using python 3.6.5:

Seqeval:

```
pip install seqeval==0.0.5
```

Keras:

```
pip install keras==2.2.4
```

Keras-contrib (2.0.8):

```
git clone https://www.github.com/keras-team/keras-contrib.git

cd keras-contrib

python setup.py install
```

TensorFlow:

```
pip install tensorflow==1.14.0
```

Do `pip list` to make sure you have actually installed those versions (eg `pip seqeval` may automatically update your keras)

Then in your code import like so:

```
from keras.models import *
from keras.layers import LSTM, Embedding, Dense, TimeDistributed, Dropout, Bidirectional, Input
from keras_contrib.layers import CRF
#etc.
```

Hope this helps, good luck!

Comment: Thank you. I mean using tensorflow.keras and crf, not keras and keras_contrib.crf.  keras and keras_contrib.crf will work, but tensorflow.keras with keras_contrib.crf will not work. I am using bert-for-tf2 which uses tensorflow.keras not keras, so I want a crf package can work well with tensorflow.keras.

Comment: That sounds to me like a completely different question from your original question. Anyway that error "AttributeError: 'Node' object has no attribute 'output_masks'" is apparently because of incompatible keras/keras contrib/tensorflow versions (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51821537/attributeerror-node-object-has-no-attribute-output-masks). So for now you probably have to play with the versions of keras/tensorflow and hopefully get something to work or wait for the developers to fix this issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can try tensorflow add-ons.(If you are using tensorflow version 2).
You can try tf-crf-layer (if you are using tensorflow==1.15.0)

Comment: Welcome. Please edit your answer according to [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

They have it mentioned on their [README](https://github.com/keras-team/keras-contrib#install-keras_contrib-for-tensorflowkeras).

```
git clone https://www.github.com/keras-team/keras-contrib.git
cd keras-contrib
python convert_to_tf_keras.py
USE_TF_KERAS=1 python setup.py install
```

Answer (score 0):

I have gone through the possible solutions, mentioning which worked for me:

1. Install tf2crf (https://pypi.org/project/tf2crf/): It provides a simple CRF layer for TensorFlow 2 keras.

[image]

2. Use TensorFlow SIG Addons: ( https://www.tensorflow.org/addons/api_docs/python/tfa/layers/CRF): It provides the functionality that is not available in core TensorFlow.

[image]

Comment: Please [try not to upload images of code/data/errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question)