# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'keras_contrib'

Tags: python, keras

I installed `keras_contrib` using:

```
pip install git+https://www.github.com/keras-team/keras-contrib.git
```

Now when I run:

```
from keras_contrib.layers import CRF
```

It gives the following error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'keras_contrib'
```

How can I find out what is this package's path in my computer so that I add it to my python path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you must install particular versions of seqeval and keras

```
pip install seqeval==0.0.5
pip install keras==2.2.4
```

Then you must git clone the keras-contrib repo. Then cd to the keras-contrib folder and do
`python setup.py install`

Finally install a particular version of tensorflow
`pip install tensorflow==1.14.0`

[See this stackoverflow post for more info](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58525197/13700906)

Answer (score 0):

When running 'pip install ' in the command line, it usually print information while installing the module. On some OSs, you can find the download location there. Otherwise, you can use the following command line code to download towards a precise directory:

```
pip install path-to-downloaded-package
```